# How to get enum Key in C# using Enum Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, variables, foreach, enums

I have 1 string variable, have Enums and need to compare incoming string variable to Enum Values, and if it finds compares, I need to take compared Enum Key and assign to some int variable. How can I do this?
I need Only Enum Key.

For Example I have :

```
public class Enums
{
  Admin = 0,
  Seller = 1,
  Member = 2,
  Unknown = 3
}
```

And Some base class:

```
string tech = “Member”;

foreach(string value in Enum.GetNames(typesof(Enums)))
{
  If(tech == value)
{
  int enumValueKey =  And here I need '2'. 
}}}
```

In Base class, I have only string type variable for example (string Admin, string Seller, string Member, string Unknown). If It finds 1 comparison , then should write Key in int value , the same value as was found in Enums.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look at `Enum.Parse`, `Enum.TryParse`

Comment: `int key = (int) (Enum.Parse<Enums>(tech));` - just `Parse` and then cast to `int` if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via `Enum.Parse` and `typeof`

```
public enum Enums
{
  Admin = 0,
  Seller = 1,
  Member = 2,
  Unknown = 3
}

int myEnum = (int)(Enums)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enums), "Seller");
Console.WriteLine(myEnum); // 1
```

Comment: It is important to mention that `nameof` is evaluated at compile time so something like `Enums enumValue = Enums.Seller; string enumName = nameof(enumValue);` would result in `"enumValue"` not `"Seller"`.

Comment: Thank you , but i need in the end take int. Exp: i have string a = "Member" and need to take his Key (number 2)

Comment: I updated my answer for your request @LevanAmashukeli